# Passing a variable by reference into a PHP extension

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-extension

I'm writing a PHP extension that takes a reference to a value and alters it.  Example PHP:

```
$someVal = "input value";
TestPassRef($someVal);
// value now changed
```

What's the right approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 2011-09-13**: 
The correct way to do this is to use the `ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO()` family of macros - see [Extending and Embedding PHP chapter 6 (Sara Golemon, Developer's Library)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X).

This example function takes one string argument by value (due to the `ZEND_ARG_PASS_INFO(0)` call) and all others after that by reference (due to the second argument to `ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO` being 1).

```
const int pass_rest_by_reference = 1;
const int pass_arg_by_reference = 0;

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO(AllButFirstArgByReference, pass_rest_by_reference)
   ZEND_ARG_PASS_INFO(pass_arg_by_reference)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

zend_function_entry my_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(TestPassRef, AllButFirstArgByReference)
};

PHP_FUNCTION(TestPassRef)
{
    char *someString = NULL;
    int lengthString = 0;
    zval *pZVal = NULL;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sz", &someString, &lengthString, &pZVal) == FAILURE)
    {
        return;
    }

    convert_to_null(pZVal);  // Destroys the value that was passed in

    ZVAL_STRING(pZVal, "some string that will replace the input", 1);
}
```

Before adding the `convert_to_null` it would leak memory on every call (I've not whether this is necessary after adding `ZENG_ARG_INFO()` calls).