# Passing multiple variables by reference in PHP 7.3 extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension, php-7.3

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters (type ZVAL) by reference in a php extension function. But I'm not getting the changed value. I followed the suggestions from the following post. [Passing a variable by reference into a PHP7 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349087/passing-a-variable-by-reference-into-a-php7-extension)

But it worked for only one argument. Below is the code in which I'm trying to pass 2 ZVALs

```
PHP_FUNCTION(sample_byref_compiletime)
{
    zval *a,*b;     
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC,
        "z/z/", &a, &b ) == FAILURE)
    {
        php_printf("Error");
        RETURN_NULL();
    }
    ZVAL_DEREF(a);
    SEPARATE_ZVAL_NOREF(a);
    zval_dtor(a);   
    ZVAL_LONG(a, 40);

    ZVAL_DEREF(b);
    SEPARATE_ZVAL_NOREF(b);
    zval_dtor(b);   
    ZVAL_LONG(b, 41);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the answer to the post you linked in your question. Although, to your credit, it was a little confusing. The answer presented two possible solutions:

1.) Change `z` to `z/` in the call to `zend_parse_parameters()`

or

2.) Add the calls to `ZVAL_DEREF(a);` and `SEPARATE_ZVAL_NOREF(a);` before reassigning the zval.

The second option essentially does what the `/` modifier would have done if provided in the call to `zend_parse_parameters()`. As [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.funcs.php) indicates:

> **Advanced Type Specifiers**
>
> **Spec**       **Description**
>
> ...
>
> `/`       `SEPARATE_ZVAL_IF_NOT_REF` on the parameter it follows
>
> ...

So you should either use just option #1 or just option #2. You applied both options at once, which means the dereference is happening twice.